# MS access in ireport

Tags: java

I need to connect ireport with ms access. I am unable to do that using java 8 and ucanaccess. I couldnt find the option to connect with ms access in ireport. Anyway connecting with odbc driver is possible in ireport but there is no way to connect it using ucanaccess(since odbc is not supported in java 8). Can you give a solution to my problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried the jdbc-odbc bridge?

Comment: It is not supported in java 8